# how to get data from xml object in org.jdom.Document?

Tags: java, xml, jdom

I am trying to get some datas from xml document object. My imaginery xml file is like that;

```
<root>
  <body> 
    <oids>
      <oid> </oid>
      <oid> </oid>
      <oid> </oid>
      <oid> </oid>
    </oids>
  </body>
</root>
```

And to do that I am writing a function for that ;

```
public Vector<String> getOIDs(Document document){ 

    Vector<String> oids = new Vector<String>();
    Element root = document.getRootElement();
    Element body = root.getChild("body");
    Element element = body.getChild("oids");
    List rows = (List) element.getChildren("oid");
    /*
              List rows = root.getChildren("oids");
              for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {

                }

            */
    return oids;
}
```

As I read from the Internet , I undeerstood that I should use List class to get the s but when I try it, I always get errors. Can you please help me to get the s.

Thank you all.

Comment: What errors?  Compile errors?  Runtime errors?  Post them.  Help us help you.  Reading this might help:  http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-05-2000/jw-0518-jdom.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see what is wrong in the code. The only thing that looks fishy is the *explicit* conversion to List. Why is that?

I'm guessing that you have imported the wrong List implementation. Make sure you have imported java.util.List.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now, if I use
List rows = body.getChildren("oid");
  for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
   Element row = (Element) rows.get(i);
   String s = row.getValue();
   oids.add(s);
  }
do u think I can get the <oid> s ?

Comment: Sorry... I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "<oid> s"?

Comment: I ment values between <oid> </oid>s in my Document object .

Comment: A few things:

**(1)** To get the row element textual value use `row.getText()` and not `row.getValue()`

**(2)** To get elements under the row element you can use the `row.getChildren("node_name");` again.

Answer (score 0):

In your XML, <body> and <oids> are siblings, i.e. they have the same parent. Your code assumes that <oids> is a child of <body>. That should hopefully get you going again.

Comment: @Ozer. Then it looks OK. If you show us the error you get we'll have a better chance helping you!

Comment: I think the List that I was using was not java.util.List so thats why I got the error.